# Scala -- how to create map from raw data to compute distinct values

Tags: scala

New to Scala and trying to read the input raw data to generate a map with groupBy on multiple fields.

Sample raw data:

```
date,uid,site,success
2014-07-14,userA,google,1
2014-07-14,userB,google,1
2014-07-14,userC,yahoo,1
2014-07-14,userD,facebook,1
```

I want to report the number of distinct users per site for each date ie,

```
2014-07-14,google,2
2014-07-14,yahoo,1
2014-07-14,facebook,1
```

For this purpose, I'm trying to use groupBy on date and site fields with value as uid. Once I have this data structure, I can iterate over the map and compute the distinct map values.
Can anyone point me to how to generate the data structure?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. How big is your input data? 2. Would you later need count of distinct users across dates?

Comment: About a million rows every day and yes will need to count distinct users across dates. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly. Here is a full example.

```
case class Data(date: String, uid: String, site: String, success: Int)

val sampleData = List(
  Data("2014-07-14","userA","google",1),
  Data("2014-07-14","userA","google",1),
  Data("2014-07-14","userB","google",1),
  Data("2014-07-14","userC","yahoo",1),
  Data("2014-07-14","userD","facebook",1)
)

sampleData.groupBy(_.date).map
  {case (date, datelist) => (date, datelist.groupBy(_.site).map
    {case (site, sitelist) => (site, sitelist.groupBy(_.uid).size)})}
```

The output is: `Map(2014-07-14 -> Map(google -> 2, yahoo -> 1, facebook -> 1))`

Basically you get a Map for each date, that contains the accesses to sites from distinct users. Notice that the 2 accesses from `userA` count as 1.

```
 sitelist.groupBy(_.uid).size
```

counts the distinct accesses by `uid`.

**Edit** Yes, it is possible without an extra data-structure. You just have to deal with the indices of arrays now.

```
val fileText = """2014-07-14,userA,google,1
  2014-07-14,userA,google,1
  2014-07-14,userA,google,1
  2014-07-14,userB,google,1
  2014-07-14,userC,yahoo,1
  2014-07-14,userD,facebook,1""".stripMargin

fileText.lines.map(_.split(",")).toList.groupBy(_(0)).map
  {case (date, datelist) => (date, datelist.groupBy(_(2)).map
    {case (site, sitelist) => (site, sitelist.groupBy(_(1)).size)})}
```

Comment: Thanks Kigyo, definitely answers my question. Since I'll be parsing the raw data external files, doesn't constructing a Data object add additional overhead? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Discarding the header line for clarity, a possible implementation is the following:

```
val text = """2014-07-14,userA,google,1
            |2014-07-14,userA,google,1
            |2014-07-14,userB,google,1
            |2014-07-14,userC,yahoo,1
            |2014-07-16,userC,yahoo,1
            |2014-07-14,userD,facebook,1
            |2014-07-14,userE,facebook,1
            |""".stripMargin

val uniqueUsersByDateSite: Map[(String, String), Int] = text.lines.map {
  line =>
    val tokens = line.split(",")
    (tokens(0), tokens(1), tokens(2))
}.toSet.groupBy {
  tuple: (String, String, String) =>
    (tuple._1, tuple._3)
}.mapValues {
  _.size
}
```

By creating a set of tuples `(date, uid, site)`, we collect an item for each unique user for a site on a specific date.

The `groupBy` method then collects by `(date, site)`, transforming N items for the same date and site to a map entry, containing a number of items corresponding to the number of unique users for the corresponding date and site.

The final `mapValue` method achieve the desired result:

```
Map((2014-07-16,yahoo) -> 1, (2014-07-14,facebook) -> 2, (2014-07-14,google) -> 2, (2014-07-14,yahoo) -> 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Luigi.. learnt some new stuff about Scala from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted @Kigyo seems pretty good, But I can think you can extend it a little : 
So, assuming this data structure :

```
case class Data(date: String, uid: String, site: String, success: Int)
val sampleData = List(
  Data("2014-07-14","userA","google",1),
  Data("2014-07-14","userA","google",1),
  Data("2014-07-14","userB","google",1),
  Data("2014-07-14","userC","yahoo",1),
  Data("2014-07-14","userD","facebook",1)
)
```

you can achieve what you want by :

```
list.groupBy((_.date , _.site)).collect{ case (a , b : List[Data]) =>(a._1 , a._2 , b.map(_.success).sum) } ;
```

which returns a list of Tuple3, just like you wanted

Comment: Yea, that depends on what kind of data-structure @user2727704 wants as a result. I also assumed that the amount of `success` is irrelevant, since the amount of distinct users has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Instead of b.map(_.success).sum are there any other ways to apply count distinct on uid itself since I may not always have a success field. Thanks!

Comment: If you want 'success' field to be used like date and site (act as a filter), the best way is to include it in the first tuple (in group by).